# How to access a variable definded with const (or let) within the global scope by its name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, constants

When i do this in JS:

```
const myConst = "something";
```

outside any function, how can I access `myConst` by its name ?

From what I have understood so far is, that myConst ends up in the "Declarative Environment Record", but i don't know how to access it other than directly, like writing

`console.log(myConst);`

Thx

`window["myConst"] //would only work if myConst would have been defined using var`

Comment: Why do you need to access a variable by its name? What are you trying to achieve? Because I think there should be a better way to solve the issue.

Comment: You can't, it's a variable. Store your data into an [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name) instead.

Comment: This question comes up all the time. In some programming languages it makes sense. In JavaScript it means you're approaching a problem with a solution inappropriate for JavaScript.

Comment: @Reyno: I developed an html element (a search box) where you can set configuration data for that element with a html property (like data-config="variableName"). So i have the name of that variable which has to be defined somewhere in your .js files.. It was a var before, but i wanted to chage it to const, hence window["variableName"] didn't work anymore